# Why is scrollbar not appearing in my react app when I load it on chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, user-interface, scrollbar

No scrollbars are appearing in my react app in any chromimum based browser(I tried brave and chrome)....I thought that there might be some problem in css but then i loaded the same app on firefox and scrollbars appear.
On firefox:
[image]

On chrome/brave:
[image]

What might have gone wrong?

Comment: What have you set your overflow to? `overflow: auto` or `overflow: scroll`? Possible that `overflow: auto` is handled differently in both browsers.

Comment: I have tried both but none of them bring scrollbar in chrome..

Comment: Ok see, from the looks of it, only if there is overflow, will a scrollbar be visible under some cases - I am not sure when exactly ( but this only happens in chrome in my experience ). So you would wanna look for that case, maybe child-parent positioning and all. Fixed width or is it taking some other relative value and things like that.

Comment: yes an overflow is there...I am able to scoll using my trackpad but the scrollbar isn't visible...

Answer (score 0):

You can add some lines of code to your CSS and fix this problem.

```css
.hide-native-scrollbar {
  scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox 64 */
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* Internet Explorer 11 */
}
.hide-native-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar { /** WebKit */
  display: none;
}
```